# SQLite: in a child table, how can I specify two foreign keys from two parent tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am implementing SQLite using c-interface in vs2012.

I have three tables, two of them are parents and they aren't linked together by any keys. the third one is a child, which should have two foreign-keys from the two parent tables. I tried the following but it is not working giving me the following error:

```
foreign key contraints failed
```

here is my implementation:
first parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Name CHAR                              NULL    ,
    Age  INT                               NULL
);
```

second parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    Job_ID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Description CHAR                              NULL    ,
    Country     CHAR
);
```

the child table

```
CREATE TABLE Persons_Jobs (
    Title   CHAR NULL,
    country CHAR NULL,
    ID      INT      ,
    Job_ID  INT      ,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID)     REFERENCES Persons(ID) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (Job_ID) REFERENCES Jobs(Job_ID)
);
```

note that my tables are created successfully, and the data on the first two tables are also inserted successfully.

---

***UPDATE 2:***

*The insertion statements:*

```
void db_prepareInsertSql(sqlite3 *db){
    sqlite3_int64 rowPersonID,rowJobID;
    int i =0;
    char *sql;
    char str[100];  

    do{
        i = i+1;
        sprintf_s(str, "INSERT INTO Persons VALUES(NULL,'liena',%d);",i);
        sql = str;
        db_execute_sql(db,sql);
        fprintf(stdout,"Persons insertion");
        rowPersonID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);

        sprintf_s(str, "INSERT INTO Jobs VALUES(NULL,'Doc','SDN');");
        sql = str;
        db_execute_sql(db,sql);
        fprintf(stdout,"Jobs insertion");
        rowJobID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);

\\the error occurs here
        sprintf_s(str, "INSERT INTO Persons_Jobs VALUES('A','krt',%d,%d);",rowPersonID,rowJobID);
        sql = str;
        db_execute_sql(db,sql);
        fprintf(stdout,"Persons_Jobs insertion");
    }
    while(i!=10);
}
```

*The table creation:*

```
void db_prepareCreateTablesSql(sqlite3 *db){    
    char *sql;
    char str[500];

    sprintf_s(str, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    sql = str;
    db_execute_sql(db,sql); 
    fprintf(stdout,"Enable foriegn-keys feature");

    sprintf_s(str, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persons("  
         "ID            INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,   " 
         "Name          CHAR                                    NULL    ,   "
         "Age           INT                                     NULL    );  ");
    sql = str;
    db_execute_sql(db,sql);
    fprintf(stdout,"table Persons");

    sprintf_s(str, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Jobs(" 
         "Job_ID        INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,   " 
         "Description   CHAR                                    NULL    ,   " 
         "Country       CHAR                                            )");         
    sql = str;
    db_execute_sql(db,sql); 
    fprintf(stdout,"table Jobs");

    sprintf_s(str, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persons_Jobs("  
         "Title         CHAR                                    NULL    ,   " 
         "country       CHAR                                    NULL    ,   " 
         "ID            INT                                             ,   "
         "Job_ID        INT                                             ,   "        
         "FOREIGN KEY   (ID)        REFERENCES      Persons(ID),"        
         "FOREIGN KEY   (Job_ID)    REFERENCES      Jobs(Job_ID))       ;");
    sql = str;
    db_execute_sql(db,sql); 
    fprintf(stdout,"table Persons_Jobs");

    db_prepareInsertSql(db);
}
```

when I debug, i found this:
[image]

so, my problem is in the child table, how can I specify two foreign keys from two different parent tables ?

Comment: @Dayalrai: thanks, it was suggested and i hit it by mistake

Comment: WHEN are you getting this error? This is an error you would get attemping to `INSERT` some data which does not respect your `FOREIGN KEY` constraints. Those table definitions are alright. You are probably trying to insert some data which is not valid according to those constraints.

Comment: Your sql statements works perfectly to me and the data are inserted to all tables successfully [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bf159](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bf159). You should show how you insert the data and the query that causes the error.

Comment: @Eggplant: check the update to see the insertion statements and where the error occurs.

Comment: @Sp.: check the update to see the insertion commands and the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
 sprintf_s(str, "INSERT INTO Persons_Jobs VALUES('A','krt',%d,%d);",rowPersonID,rowJobID);
```

The type of `rowPersonID` and `rowJobID` is `sqlite3_int64`:

```
sqlite3_int64 rowPersonID,rowJobID;
```

which is 64bit type while `%d` expects an integer, 32bit. You need to cast it to integer or use `I64d` to format 64bit number:

```
sprintf_s(str, "INSERT INTO Persons_Jobs VALUES('A','krt',%I64d,%I64d);", rowPersonID,rowJobID);
```

Answer (score 3):

The two inserts in the two tables (`Persons` and `Jobs`) may result in two different auto incremented values. So you should catch them both with (pseudo-code):

```
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES(NULL,'liena',1);       // 1st table
rowPersonID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db)       // catch PersonID

INSERT INTO Jobs VALUES(NULL,'Doc','SDN'); // 2nd table
rowJobID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db)       // catch JobID
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO Career VALUES('A','krt',%d,%d)",rowPersonID,rowJobID;
```

Comment: thanks for this very useful tip .. though, still not working .. giving me the same error

Comment: I am not to put the full code .. but there is snap of it in  "Update 2:" above